# C++ demo programming ,confusing for class implement

Tags: c++, class, static

I have encountered a c++ demo programming source ,it contain a header file called A.h , and a shared library called X.so , The following is the A.h like :

```
#if !defined(A_H)
#define A_H

class aAPI
{
public:    
    static aAPI* createaAPI(const char*FlowPath = "");
    virtual  void Init() = 0 ;
    virtual  void Release() = 0 ;
    virtual const char *GetDay() = 0;
    virtual void RegisterU(char *pU) = 0;
protected:
    ~aAPI(){};
};
#endif
```

All functions in aAPI class are pure virtual functions , so it can not be used to create object,
the demo of this aAPI look like :

```
aAPI* ptr ;
ptr = aAPI::createaAPI("logtest");
strcpy(tradingDay, ptr->GetDay());
```

I am tring to code a.cpp  like :

```
#include "a.h"

aAPI* aAPI::createaAPI(const char*FlowPath )
{
    //return this ;
}
```

But I figure out that I can not return this since 'this' is not available for static member function,
and then I noticed that class aAPI in A.h has no private member data , so I think in X.so , there should be  codes  to declare class aAPI private member data to keep data passed by createaAPI or RegisterU !!

I like to know how a.cpp in my case , to return a pointer to aAPI , and then how to declare private member data of aAPI in a.cpp ?!

```
Edit :

 Here comes the simple source for this case :
```

a.h

```
#if !defined(A_H)
#define A_H
class aAPI
{
public:
   static aAPI* createaAPI(const char*FlowPath = "");
   virtual  void Init() = 0 ;
   virtual  void Release() = 0 ;
   virtual const char *GetDay() = 0;
protected:
   ~aAPI(){};
};
#endif
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

aAPI* aAPI::createaAPI(const char*FlowPath)
{
    static aAPI* ptr = 0x00 ;
    if(ptr==0x00)
    {
        ptr = new bAPI(FlowPath) ;
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

b.h

```
#if !defined(B_H)
#define B_H

#include "a.h"

class bAPI:public aAPI
{
private:
    char path[100] ;
    char strday[11] ;
public:
    bAPI(const char*FlowPath)
    {
        strcpy(path,FlowPath) ;
    }
    virtual  void Init() ;
    virtual  void Release() ;
    virtual const char *GetDay() ;
} ;

void bAPI::Init()
{
    strcpy(strday,"2014/01/02") ;
}
void bAPI::Release()
{
}
const char* bAPI::GetDay()
{
    return strday;
}
#endif
```

amain.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
using namespace std ;

int main()
{
    aAPI* ptr = aAPI::createaAPI("hello world") ;
    ptr->Init();
    cout << ptr->GetDay() << endl ;
}
```

and then :

```
g++ --std=c++0x a.cpp amain.cpp -o amain.exe
```

will get the demo done !! .... thanks a lot !!!!

Comment: Somewhere there must be a reference to what `X.so` contains? Without a header file that library is utterly useless.

Comment: As the `aAPI` class is an abstract class, it's meant to be used as a base for inheriting. It seems to me that you should check the string passed to `createAPI` and use it to figure out which child-class you should create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header specifies an interface the shared library conforms to. The library most probably contains classes derived from `aAPI` as well as implementation of `aAPI`'s methods. `static aAPI* createaAPI(const char*FlowPath = "")` is a factory method - it instantiates derived classes and returns them as a pointer to the base class.

You can create your own classes conforming to the interface by deriving them from `aAPI` and implementing the abstract methods. As long as you link against `X.so`, however, you won't be able to create your derived class with the factory method because you won't be allowed to provide a second implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the [Abstract Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) where the factory is the method `createaAPI`.

The idea is that you should derive the class `aAPI` to provide classes which can be instantiated, or that the library already provide several subclasses. The ***design issue here*** is that the implementation of `createaAPI` should already know the subclasses.